# What is 'stockbeinig'?

Tags: meaning

I came across the following sentence in *Der Spiegel*:

> Fotografen sind abhängig vom Auftraggeber, vom Kunden, von der Konkurrenz und immer wieder auch vom Objekt: denn was macht ein Fotograf, wenn der Abzulichtende stockbeinig in die Kamera grinst und einfach keinen locker-lässigen Kate-Moss-Look hinbekommt?

What does 'stockbeinig' mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A literal translation would be *"stick-legged*. It's a describing word combination, meaning the photographer's subject is standing stiff and errect instead of in a relaxed, "cool" pose.

A probably more common term would be *[steifbeinig](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/steifbeinig)*.

Comment: http://michaelbittner.info/2016/04/25/die-sprachpolizei-informiert-1-ironie-fuer-idioten/

Comment: @userunknown  feel free to edit.